# Convert Binary to Blob in php

Tags: php, binary, blob

How can I create blob object from binary file in php? This is my last code :

```
foreach ($results as $key) {
        $content = base64_decode($key['file_proposal']);
        $file = $key['nama_file_proposal'];
        file_put_contents($file, $content);

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
```

my code produce error message "file format or file extension is not valid" so i wanna change $content as a blob object because i created a code in js for download file but it using blob. this is my js code :

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"}));
    const link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'Detail Blast.xlsx');
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "blob" object? Like with sample input and desired output?

Comment: @mario done, i edited my question :)

Comment: Your code works here. What's wrong?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i can download my file. But when i open it, it produce "file format or file extension is not valid" error message. what should i do?

Comment: What is `response.data`?